# Tab recovery from a corrupt Chrome Last Session?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-tabs, file-corruption, recovery

Chrome crashed and I lost ~100 tabs. The tabs don't appear in history and I'm not able to restore them by renaming my Last Session file to Current Session in AppData/Google/UserData/Default, it just opens a new blank tab.

I have created a backup of the Default folder. Is there any way to recover my tabs from my Last Session file? The file appears as 3.5 Mb but, opening it with Notepad, it just contains "SNSS" and a bunch of blank lines. Does this mean it has been corrupted?

I have not had any luck with ccl-snss-master or lsauer.net

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue with lsauer.net chrome session restore on my 2.5MB Last Session file. [Chromagnon](https://github.com/JRBANCEL/Chromagnon/wiki/Reverse-Engineering-SSNS-Format) is telling me my Current Session file is corrupted, but maybe it may work for you?

Following to see if anyone has a way of repairing a corrupted Last Session file.